# Purplish discoloration on the leaves of solanum torvum

Tags: diseases, nightshade

Recently my Solanum torvum started developing purplish discoloration on the leaves

[image]

It is visible primarily on the top surface of the leaf, and lower, older leaves are more affected than the top ones.

The plant is a few months old, and is kept indoors, on the south side of a building.

What can be the cause of that?

Comment: Is it spring or fall? Daylength is currently changing rapidly. How old is the plant?

Comment: @WayfaringStranger It is fall, and the plant is kept indoors (though on a south facing room), so light conditions can be a factor.